# awk digit range match of first column

Tags: awk, freebsd

On FreeBSD I would like to disable all consoles but the first (ttyv0) automatically from a shell script. This seems to be easier to do with AWK than with SED but if someone knows a way to do this with SED please also share it.

```
With awk this will work for a single console:
  awk '/ttyv1/ { sub(/onifexists/,"off") } 1' /etc/ttys 
However this will NOT:
  awk '/ttyv{1-8}/ { sub(/onifexists/,"off") } 1' /etc/ttys
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3):

With your shown attempts, could you please try following. This should catch tty0 to tty8 and do the changes in line then.

```
awk '/ttyv[0-8]/ { sub(/onifexists/,"off") } 1' /etc/ttys
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy to do in sed:

```sh
sed -e '/ttyv[0-8]/{s/onifexists/off/}' /etc/ttys
```